# Handle Duplicate usernames and emails FastAPI

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to have unique usernames and email addresses in my application I've implement this functionality in the API but couldn't figure out a way to implement it into frontend. I am using simple Bootstrap as frontend. However, when I try to register the user it works fine user get the email to verify and vice versa but unfortunately I'm getting `ROLLBACK` error during second attempt with the same email and username instead of `Duplicate username or email` error.

ERROR:

```
2021-08-08 00:02:36,148 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 6.656s ago] ('adaasf', 'hyrepuvo@microcreditoabruzzo.it', '$2b$12$9Aqtw/1eHkJTa3u4Q2mDyODmO7LpCusE4G1UC7s2JZUbfmsoa8AE6', False, False, UUID('9dc9ebbb-d5ca-4cb1-94b2-cd088e94e7da'))
2021-08-08 00:02:36,154 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:49865 - "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
```

I have a simple form, a simple model and a basic route.
**webapp/route_users.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import Request
from fastapi import Depends
from fastapi import responses
from fastapi import status
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

from web_apps.users.forms import UserCreateForm
from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from depends import get_user_db
from core.auth import Auth
from core.mailer import Mailer


router = APIRouter(include_in_schema=False)
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@router.get("/register/")
def register(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("users/register.html", 
    {"request": request})

@router.post("/register/")
async def register_user(request: Request, user_reg: Users = Depends(get_user_db)):
    form = UserCreateForm(request)
    await form.load_data()
    if await form.is_valid():
        user = UserCreate(username=form.username, email=form.email, password=form.password)
        try:
            user = await user_reg.create_user(user=user)
            confirmation_token = Auth.get_confirmation_token(
                            user.email,
                            user.confirmation)

            # SEND AN EMAIL WITH TOKEN
            try:
                Mailer.send_confirmation_message(
                    confirmation_token["token"], form.email)
            except ConnectionRefusedError:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    detail="Email couldn't be send. Please try again."
                )
            return {f"Hello {user.username}, thanks for choosing our services. Please check your email to activate your account."}

        except IntegrityError:
            form.__dict__.get("errors").append("Duplicate username or email")
            return templates.TemplateResponse("users/register.html", form.__dict__)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("users/register.html", form.__dict__)
```

**webapp/users/forms.py**

```
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import Request

class UserCreateForm:
    def __init__(self, request: Request):
        self.request: Request = request
        self.errors: List = []
        self.username: Optional[str] = None
        self.email: Optional[str] = None
        self.password: Optional[str] = None

    async def load_data(self):
        form = await self.request.form()
        self.username = form.get("username")
        self.email = form.get("email")
        self.password = form.get("password")

    async def is_valid(self):
        
        if not self.username or not len(self.username) > 4:
            self.errors.append("Username must be > 4 characters")

        if not self.email or not (self.email.__contains__("@")):
            self.errors.append("Valid email is required")

        if not self.password or not len(self.password) > 5:
            self.errors.append("Password should be > 5")

        # if await users.get_user_by_email(email=self.email) is not None:
        #     self.errors.append("Email address is already use")

        # if await Users.get_user_by_username(username=self.username) is not None:
        #     self.errors.append("Username is already use")

        if not self.errors:
            return True

        return False
```

**db/repository/users_data_access_layer.py**

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, status
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists


from db.models.users import User
from schemas.users import UserCreate
from core.hashing import Hasher
from core.auth import Auth


db_session = Session

class Users():
    
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        self.db_session = db_session

    
    async def save(self, user_instance):
        try:
            self.db_session.add(user_instance)
            await self.db_session.flush()
        except Exception as error:
            await self.db_session.rollback()
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

    
    async def get_user_by_id(self, id):
        user = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.id==id))
        return user.scalar_one_or_none()

    
    async def get_user_by_username(self, username):
        user = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.username==username))
        return user.scalar_one_or_none()

    
    async def get_user_by_email(self, email):
        user = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.email==email))
        return user.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def get_user_by_confirmation(self, confirmation):
        user = await self.db_session.execute(select(User).filter(User.confirmation==confirmation))
        return user.scalar_one_or_none()

    async def create_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
                        email=user.email,
                        hashed_password=Auth.get_password_hash(user.password),
                        is_active=False
                        )
        await self.save(new_user)
        return new_user

    async def authenticate_user(self, username, password):
        user = await self.get_user_by_username(username=username)
        
        if not user:
            return False
        if not Auth.verify_password(password, user.hashed_password):
            return False

        return user
```

**db/models/users.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from db.base_class import Base


class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    is_superuser = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    confirmation = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    jobs = relationship("Job", back_populates="owner")
```

I tried several things like creating the function to check the database if username or email is present or not in `webapps/users/forms.py` and it produces `TypeError: execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'statement'`

tried_code:

```
from typing import List, Optional
from fastapi import Request

from db.repository.users_data_access_layer import Users
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

users = Users(db_session=Session)


class UserCreateForm:
    def __init__(self, request: Request):
        self.request: Request = request
        self.errors: List = []
        self.username: Optional[str] = None
        self.email: Optional[str] = None
        self.password: Optional[str] = None

    async def load_data(self):
        form = await self.request.form()
        self.username = form.get("username")
        self.email = form.get("email")
        self.password = form.get("password")

    async def is_valid(self):
        
        if not self.username or not len(self.username) > 4:
            self.errors.append("Username must be > 4 characters")

        if not self.email or not (self.email.__contains__("@")):
            self.errors.append("Valid email is required")

        if not self.password or not len(self.password) > 5:
            self.errors.append("Password should be > 5")

        if await users.get_user_by_email(email=self.email) is not None:
            self.errors.append("Email address is already use")

        if await users.get_user_by_username(username=self.username) is not None:
            self.errors.append("Username is already use")

        if not self.errors:
            return True

        return False
```

I simply want to handle data duplication like username and email and show it to the user in the frontend. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The console should show a stacktrace which will tell you _were_ the error was. An 500 error tells you that something went wrong in your Python-code somewhere.

Comment: I think it is failing duplicate registration in the database hence the rollback error that I got it but the point is how to solve it in a user friendly manner like instead of showing the user 500 internal server error I'd like to show the simple error msg like: Email or username already in use

Comment: Usually the database middle layer will issue a ROLLBACK if the response status code is anything else than 200/300. The ROLLBACK might be because of the 500 error, not the other way around. The uvicorn / console log should tell you exactly what caused the 500 error.

Comment: it is just showing this log `2021-08-08 00:36:35,647 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 6.258s ago] ('adaasf', 'hyrepuvo@microcreditoabruzzo.it', '$2b$12$fXefERH8Bto0xJs1ZLcimujfdvF9Ta1kiGd8Ffj9ypVVG.v4i/aca', False, False, UUID('2a3e8fd9-c67e-49c1-986f-0f6a823b08fe'))
2021-08-08 00:36:35,660 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50113 - "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: @snakecharmerb No, I tried creating user `UserCreate` inside the try/except block still getting the same `500 Internal server`

Comment: If I remove `Integrity` exception and check user and email before registering the user user it worked as expected. If I move with bare exception does it make any difference code wise?

Comment: I'd suggest temporarily removing all the exception handling in order to get a full traceback (or maybe use logging.exception). As it is we're just guessing where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

Schemes with pydantic

```
 class UserBase(BaseModel):
        fullname:str
        email:str 
        password:str
```

Models with sqlalchemy

```
class DBUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    fullname = Column(String)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    password = Column(String)
```

User create

```
async def create_user_db(db: Session, request: UserBase):
        new_user = DBUser(
            fullname=request.fullname,
            email = request.email,
            password = Hash.hash_pass(request.password)
        )
        try:
            db.add(
                new_user
            )
            db.commit()
            db.refresh(new_user)
            return new_user
    
        except:
            
            raise HTTPException(status_code=409, detail="This email alredy registered")
```

You need to handle exception like this.
It worked for me ...